# VBA EXCEL: How to call a subroutine in another subroutine?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

   'Here I want my code
   Sub Licenses()
Dim transientLicense As Integer
    Dim steadyLicense As Integer
    Dim staticLicense As Integer
    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, elem As Variant

    arr1 = Array("radial vibration", "acceleration", "acceleration2", "velocity", "velocity2") '<--| set your first values list
    arr2 = Array("axial vibration", "temperature", "pressure") '<--| set your 2nd values list
    With Worksheets("Rack Properties") '<-| reference your relevant worksheet
        With .Range("D1", Cells(Rows.Count, "AH").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns D to AH range from row 1 down to column AH last not empty row
            For Each elem In arr1 '<--| loop through 1st array list
                transientLicense = transientLicense + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "active", .Columns(20), "yes", .Columns(31), elem) '<-- update 'transientLicense' for every record matching: "active" in referenced range column 1(i.e. "D"), "yes" in referenced range column 20 (i.e. "W") and current list element in referenced range column 31 (i.e. "AH")
                steadyLicense = steadyLicense + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "active", .Columns(20), "no", .Columns(31), elem) '<-- update 'steadyLicense' for every record matching: "active" in referenced range column 1(i.e. "D"), "no" in referenced range column 20 (i.e. "W") and current list element in referenced range column 31 (i.e. "AH")
            Next elem
            For Each elem In arr2 '<--| loop through 2nd array list
                staticLicense = staticLicense + WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Columns(1), "active", .Columns(31), elem) '<-- update 'staticLicense' for every record matching: "active" in referenced range column 1(i.e. "D") and current list element in referenced range column 31 (i.e. "AH")
            Next elem
        End With
    End With

 With Worksheets.Add
        .Name = "Results"
        .Columns("B:D").ColumnWidth = 20
        .Range("B2:D2").Value = Array("Transient Licenses", "Steady Licenses", "Static Licenses")
        .Range("B3:D3").Value = Array(transientLicense, steadyLicense, staticLicense)
    End With
End Sub



    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I want to open all the excel sheets in a given folder and count the total no of licenses in each sheet and display the output in another workbook.
I have just started learning VBA and I am not able to use it in a macro.
A little help is really appreciated.
thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep your routines separate, and then call one from the other.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim counter As Long
  For counter = 1 to 5
    DoSomething
  Next counter
End Sub

Sub DoSomething()
  Beep
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply do it this way.

```
Sub RunSub1

'...code
'...code
'...code

Call SubRun2
End Sub

Sub SubRun2
'will now have access to Var1 and Var2 as defined in SubRun1
End Sub
```

You can even just use the name of the Sub; you don't really need the 'Call' part.

Comment: The `Call` statement is obsolete, and should be avoided.